# HTML DIV Positioning

Tags: html

i'm having this problem........

```
<div id="Div_DefaultPage">
      <div id="Div_inner1">

      </div>

      <div id="Div_inner2">

      </div>
</div>
```

what i want to do is, i have a combobox which have 2 choice - inner1, inner2.
if user select inner2, inner1 will hidden and inner2 will display on the top of Div_DefaulPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use Javascript to show and hide divs. [Here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/slicker-show-and-hide) is a tutorial of how you'd accomplish that.
Try your hardest to follow the examples. If you have a problem trying it then post your code and we'll try to help you out. Good luck!